# How to write the SQL query for this?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

My SQL Server table contains those columns :

```
ID      Product      fare       s1from         s1to            s1fare
1       Pen          500        9-Mar-2011     14-Mar-2011     400
2       copy         800        15-Mar-2011    10-Mar-201      900
3       Pencil       900        20-Mar-2011    25-Mar-2011     1000
```

I have two textboxes on web form.

When user enters a date between `s1from` date 9-Mar-2011 in textbox1 and `s1to` date 13-Mar-2011 in textbox 2 then the fare in textbox3 will be 400 else 500

How to write a SQL query for this?

Comment: We can suggest you many ways to achieve this, but your table structure does not look quite good. Split it and make it better.

Comment: Two questions: What happens if I enter a date like `2011-03-01`? What happens if I enter a date like `2011-03-15`? I.e., how would it ever know to use the value in the `fare` column vs the `s1fare` column? Is the user required to choose a Product?

Comment: Here is a question from someone else that seams to be working on almost the same problem. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5220669/whats-wrong-in-this-query. You might get something from those answers as well.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the query from your presentation layer is a parameterized query (and that you have verified that the textbox values are really dates), your query would look something like (I'm also assuming the user had to choose a product):

```
Select Case
        When @UserDateValue Between s1from And s1to Then s1fare
        Else fare
        End As fare
From MyTable
Where Product = @Product
```

Answer (score 0):

here @ date and @fare is user defined variable or input

```
Select * from table 
where (@date between s1from   and s1to )
and fare       = @fare
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Declare @dateFrom as datetime
Declare @dateTo as datetime
set @dateFrom = '03/09/2011' -- this is the value from textbox 1
set @dateTo = '03/13/2011' -- this is the value from textbox 2

-- this query returns the fare based on the inputted values on dateFrom and dateTo
Select 
    TheFare=Case when @dateFrom >= Cast(Convert(varchar(20),s1from,101) as datetime) and
    @dateTo <= Cast(Convert(varchar(20),s1To,101) as datetime) then
    s1fare
    else fare
    end 
From YourTable
```